# Percentage error in diameter given percentage error in surface area.

Tags: calculus

I am given a cylinder with a height of 10m.

I am tasked with finding the maximum percentage error in measuring the exterior diameter of the tank, given that the maximum error in surface area is 8%.

I have gotten to $\frac{(4{\pi}r+20\pi)dr}{(2{\pi}r^2+20{\pi}r)}=.08$
but I am not sure how to continue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to **estimate** the diameter by measuring the surface area?

Answer (score 1):

The surface area is given by $S(d) = \pi( dh + {1 \over 2} d^2)$. Given a
surface area $A\ge 0$, there is a unique $d$ such that $S(d) = A$ and this is given by
$\delta(A) = \sqrt{2 {A \over \pi} +h^2}-h$.

Hence if $A$ is the correct area and $A(1+ \epsilon)$ is the measured area, you
want to compute $\Delta=\max_{|\epsilon| \le 0.08} | {\delta(A(1+\epsilon)) \over \delta(A)} -1| $. Since $\delta$ is an increasing function and it's derivative $\delta'$ is decreasing, we see that
$\Delta = 1-{\delta(A(1-0.08)) \over \delta(A)}$.